# Angular2: print an object that I recivced from function

Tags: angular, ionic2

First of all this is the git: https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/blob/DB-LINKED/src/pages/Medicine/Medicine.ts
as you can see this line in the code:

`this.Medicines = this.networkServices.showMedicines();` - LN.16 Medicine.ts

The function `showMedicines()` is pulling out data from MongoDB collection.

Data: `[{
"_id":"586a048e34e5c12614a7424a","name":"מיקוטיל","price":350,"amount":1,"desc":"תרופה למניעת דלקת ריאות","rate":"1CC ל30KG","type":"הזרקה לשריר","comment":"יש להיזהר מהחומר בזמן ההזרקה.","__v":0
}]`

I want to print this object inside Medicine.html, as you can see I have set var Medicines that use the function to get the object.
but I get this problem:

`inline template:19:7 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over Data and not over the response. `*ngFor="let row of Medicines.Data"`

```
<div *ngFor="let currentMedicine of Medicines.Data"> // HERE
  {{currentMedicine.name}}
</div>
```

Or just assing Medicines.Data to the Medicines variable instead, like:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public networkServices: NetworkServices) {
  this.Medicines = this.networkServices.showMedicines().Data; // HERE
}
```

Comment: Data isn't recognized what is it?

Comment: As you said: "The function showMedicines() is pulling out data from MongoDB collection.

Data: [{
"_id":"586a048e34e5c12614a7424a","name":"מיקוטיל","price":350,"amount":1,"desc":"תרופה למניעת דלקת ריאות","rate":"1CC ל30KG","type":"הזרקה לשריר","comment":"יש להיזהר מהחומר בזמן ההזרקה.","__v":0
}]

"

Comment: pulling out the data from mongo its not a variable